# Finding $f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)=\ln(x-2)+\ln(x+2)$

so what will be the inverse $f^{-1}(x)$?

**My attempt:**

$$f(x)=\ln(x-2)+\ln(x+2)$$

$$=\ln(x^2-4)$$

$$\Longrightarrow f^{-1}(x)=e^{x^2-4}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: when you take the $log$ ,it will become$e^{f(x)}=(x^2-4)$

Comment: So, where is my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\log(x^2-4)$$
$$e^{f(x)}=e^{\log(x^2-4)}=x^2-4$$
$$x^2=4+e^{f(x)}$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{4+e^{f(x)}}$$

So what would be your $f^{-1}$, considering the domain of $x$?

Comment: This is my quastion

Comment: what would be my $f {−1}$

Comment: How do you find an inverse generally, and then how is the content of my post related to it?

Answer (score 1):

not really, all good up to

$y = \ln(x^2-4)$

then,

$e^y = x^2 - 4$

$ x = \pm \sqrt(e^y + 4)$

We will drop the negative solution as extraneous, so the resulting function is $\sqrt(e^y + 4)$

Comment: so what will be $f^{-1}$?

Comment: $x$ must be greater than $2$ for the original equation to make sense.

Comment: Only positive solution makes sense, as the original function is defined for x>2, so $f^{-1} = \sqrt{(e^x + 4)}$

Answer (score 1):

Once you have gotten as far as
$$f(x) = \ln (x^2-4)$$
you can approach the problem as follows.  The function $f(x)$ does three things, in this order:  Given any variable $x$, you:

1. Square $x$
2. Take the result of step 1 and subtract $4$ from it
3. Take the result of step 2 and compute $\ln$ of it

An inverse function would reverse those steps, in reverse order.  In other words it would take any input $x$ and:

1. Compute $e^x$
2. Take the result of step 1 and add $4$ to it
3. Take the result of step 2 and compute its square root

If you can write that out as a formula, you're done.